# Googlebot not indexing https pages with 301 redirect

Tags: google-search-console, https, googlebot

I recently installed a new SSL in my blog and i forced 301 redirect on all http to https pages. It took like 2 months for google to index https content, infact i am seeing a small boost in rankings. The site has over 600 posts.

The only problem i face, google is not indexing fresh posts published in the site. Earlier with old site using http, google used to index newly published posts within a minute or so.

I am using wordpress, and i submitted both http and https versions in google webmasters console. I see no crawl errors, except it shows xmlrpc.php 405 errors.

How else i fix the indexing problem?

Comment: Basically, you started over when you switched to HTTPS, therefore, all of you old metrics are gone including any freshness scores. This is a TTL style metric that will move based upon discovery. This does not happen quickly. But it will happen. You will just have to be patient. Google has to discover the freshness, popularity, trend value, and other similar metrics all over again. Sorry. That is just the way it is. Cheers!!